# Directives doesn't work in called view but fine in the index.html page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, bower, yeoman

*Hi,

I just start to use AngularJS to make applications and I just found a weird problem. I search for similar issues nevertheless I didn't find anything to solve it - that's why i'm here folks ! :) -.*

**My project specifications :** AngularJS, NodeJS, Yeoman, Grunt, Bower
The "main" of my website is `index.html`. It contains the header, the footer and this is it where I include all the common stuff (navbar, etc...) and the ng-view.
I'm working on `localhost:3502`.

Like I said in the title, all the directives are not working in my ng-view.
However, anything is fine in the `index.html` page.
I had activated the debug mode but there was no error !
I will show you an exemple.

**index.html**

```
<html ng-app="3DevApp">
  <head>
    // ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- I work very good, sir -->
    <div ng-controller="ViewCtrl">
      <button ng-click="changeView('HelloWorld')">Say hi</button>
    </div>

    <div ng-view></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
angular.module('3DevApp')
  .controller('ViewCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.changeView = function(view) {
      $location.path(view);
    }
  });
```

So, **this is working great**. The ng-view changed (the default loaded view is `main.html`).
And now, if I copy and past the code in the my main view `main.html` the directive **will not work**.
Any of them in fact.

**main.html**

```
<!-- I dunno want to work :) -->
<div ng-controller="ViewCtrl">
  <button ng-click="changeView('HelloWorld')">Say hi</button>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Two words : Holly shit.
I found the solution by my own after hours of search...
My others controllers weren't automatically include by bower.
I included them manually and now it works even if these controllers have nothing in common with this controller...
Sorry.